# Applescript Error cannot make to unicode text

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to write a simple applescript script to get the contents of WriteRoom (a simple text editor) and run it through a markdown parser then copy the resulting html to the clipboard:

```
tell application "WriteRoom" to activate
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "a" using command down
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "c" using command down
set the clipboard to (do shell script "cd ~;echo \"" & (the clipboard) & "\" >> writeroom.md; /usr/local/bin/markdown writeroom.md")
```

but when I run it I get an error *sometimes*:

```
 Can’t make {«class RTF »:«data RTF 7B5C727466315C616E73695C616E7369637067313235325C636F636F61727466313033385C636F636F617375627274663335300A7B5C666F6E7474626C5C66305C6673776973735C6663686172736574302048656C7665746963613B7D0A7B5C636F6C6F7274626C3B5C7265643235355C677265656E3235355C626C75653235353B7D0A5C706172645C74783536305C7478313132305C7478313638305C7478323234305C7478323830305C7478333336305C7478333932305C7478343438305C7478353034305C7478353630305C7478363136305C7478363732305C716C5C716E61747572616C5C7061726469726E61747572616C0A0A5C66305C66733332205C636630202A20746573745C0A2A20617364665C0A2A206E6F5C0A2A207465737474657374746573747D», «class utf8»:"* test
* asdf
* no
* testtesttest", «class ut16»:"* test
* asdf
* no
* testtesttest", uniform styles:«data ustl0200000090000000000000001400000020000000010000002100000000000000010000006C000000040000000000000000000000020100000100000000000000050100002C000000646D616E2400000001000000040000000100000000000000000000000900000048656C76657469636100000006010000040000000000100007010000060000000000000000000000»} into type Unicode text.
```

The selected text doesn't seem to be copied to the clipboard, instead whatever I had on my clipboard is converted. Any ideas?

Comment: You sometimes have to add a short (< 0.1s) delay between copying and getting the clipboard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that text from your application is copied as a RTF stream. To convert it to a simple text please try using `as text`:

```
(the clipboard as text)
```

**Update**

After reading your question again, I I've downloaded WriteRoom and came up with this solution:

```
tell application "WriteRoom" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "WriteRoom"
        set content to (value of text area 1 of scroll area 1 of front window) as text
    end tell
end tell

display dialog content
```

Then you can use the `content` variable for further processing. Use the Mac program *Accessibility Inspector* to find out the UI definition of any window as I did.

Comment: I've tried using `(the clipboard as text)` but it still doesn't work *all the time* and sometimes I get an error: "error "An error of type -25130 has occurred." number -25130"

Comment: Can you try for testing to set the clipboard to a static text to see whether it will then work out? If so, you will have to find another way how to convert the RTF. Please post the outcome of your test. E. g.: `tell application "Finder" to set the clipboard to "some clipboard text"`

Comment: only running `set the clipboard to "asdf"` works but when I add `tell application "System Events" to keystroke "c" using command down` it fails again

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your question properly. Your problem is that the selected text is not copied from your application WriteRoom. I will try to check it out.

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question and I see you got the fix.
But seeing that I get the same *"An error of type -25130 has occurred. Number -25130"*  with an Applescript (not using WriteRoom, using Sigil) I find out another fix in these cases.

Often it's really very important to add a small `delay` using GUI scripting. And actually even with some pre-selected text and just having a single `keystroke` I got that error. Not so if `delay 0.1` before and after `keystroke` (or you have to play with different delay 0.2 and so on).

```
delay 0.1
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "c" using command down
delay 0.1
```