# Can't make Unix ID of Process into text?

Tags: shell, text, applescript, kill-process

I have a modbook with a glitchy digitizer board. Until I can re-shield the cable that is causing the glitch I just want to turn the digitizer off. I found a page which taught me some code and I used it successfully last night. Upon reboot, however, it doesn't work anymore:

**The script**:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set PTD to (unix id of process "PenTabletDriver") as text
    do shell script "kill -STOP " & quoted form of (PTD)
end tell
```

**The error message**:

> error "Can’t make «class idux» of «class prcs» \"PenTabletDriver\" of
>   application \"System Events\" into type text." number -1700 from
>   «class idux» of «class prcs» "PenTabletDriver" to text

Can I alter the code somehow to fix this problem?

*PS:
I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865104/applescript-error-cannot-make-to-unicode-text) and, though it's similar, I do not understand how it could be applied to my problem.*

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code. You are getting the error because "System Events" is unable to find the process.

Answer (score 0):

Life is too short to mess with AppleScript. Try running the following command at the terminal prompt:

```
pkill -STOP PenTabletDriver
```

Also, check your login items to see if the driver is automatically started each time you log in. (More likely, though, is that it's configured to start at boot time via `launchd`.)

Answer (score 0):

You can save the following script in a little applet:

```
set shellStr to "pkill -STOP PenTabletDriver"
do shell script shellStr
```

and run it whenever you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think the other answers make a good point, a shell command is nice and quick. BUT, if you must have it in AppleScript, this seems to work for me....

```
tell application "System Events"
    set PTD to (unix id of process "iTunes")
    do shell script "kill -STOP " & quoted form of (PTD as text)
end tell
```

which results to

```
tell application "System Events"
    get unix id of process "iTunes"
        --> 37987
    do shell script "kill -STOP '37987'"
        --> error number -10004
end tell
tell current application
    do shell script "kill -STOP '37987'"
        --> ""
end tell
```

The Process ID is just a number so there is no need to quote it...

```
tell application "System Events"
    set PTD to (unix id of process "iTunes")
    do shell script "kill -STOP " & PTD
end tell
```

The above code is sufficient.