# AppleScript: "Can't make «handler generateNo» into type text" but it is a string?

Tags: string, text, character-encoding, arguments, applescript

I call a method like this:

```
inputByName("number", 0, my generateNo as text)
```

`generateNo` is a method that creates a string with numbers

```
generateNo ()
    set theString to "1234"
    return theString as text
end
```

`inputByName` looks like this:

```
to inputByName(theName, num, theValue)
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        tell active tab of front window
            execute javascript "document.getElementsByName('" & theName & "')[" & num & "].value ='" & theValue & "';"
        end tell
    end tell
end inputByName
```

**When I run this it chokes on the execute-statement with the error message `Can't make «handler generateNo» into type text` (my translation). Why? How do I fix?**

I read this [Applescript Error cannot make to unicode text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865104/applescript-error-cannot-make-to-unicode-text) but that didn't really apply. I have tried different variants på "as text", "as string", as «class utf8» etc, but everything just returns the same error. The string I pass is just numbers 0-9 so unicode etc are not necessary.

Comment: You don't need those coercions as everything is already text, but your example runs in Monterey - is there something else in the real handler that can be causing the problem?  Also, unless that is a typo, the `on/to` part of the `generateNo()` handler declaration is missing.

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 errors in your script. 2 of them are critical, 2 others are not critical.

**2 critical errors**: Each handler must be prefixed with the keyword **"on"** or **"to"** when it is defined.
The handler must be called in the same form as it is defined. In your case, **empty parentheses are required**.

**2 non-critical errors**: Since the generateNo() handler returns a text, the additional **coercion to the text is unnecessarily**. When calling a handler from the top level of a script (from an implicit or explicit **on run()** handler), the **"my"** keyword can be omitted. This keyword is used when calling handlers from application tell blocks or from lower-level handlers.

```
inputByName("number", 0, generateNo()) -- note the parentheses (required) 
-- additional coercion no need, keyword "my" no need (optional)

to generateNo() -- note the keyword "to" (required)
    set theString to "1234"
    return theString
end generateNo

to inputByName(theName, num, theValue)
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        tell active tab of front window
            execute javascript "document.getElementsByName('" & theName & "')[" & num & "].value ='" & theValue & "';"
        end tell
    end tell
end inputByName
```